# Python Find n words before and after a certain words

Tags: python, regex, numpy

Lets say that I have a text file. which i should read and it will be like:

```
 ... Department of Something is called (DoS) and then more texts and more text...
```

and then "while" I am reading the text file I find  an acronym, here it is

```
DoS
```

So for finding the acronym i wrote:

```
import re
import numpy

# open the file? 
test_string = " a lot of text read from file ... Department of Something is called (DoS) and then more texts and more text..."
regex = r'\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[A-Z]\b\.?'

found= re.findall(regex, test_string)
print found
```

and the output is:

```
['DoS']
```

what I want to do is:

1. WHILE I am reading the file and find and acronym (here is DoS),
2. calculate the number of characters of what i found (here is 3 chars for Dos)
3. find 2 times (here is 2x3=6) words BEFORE and AFTER the 'Dos'. here will be:

   ```
   3.1 pre=     Department of Something is called
   3.2 acronym= DoS
   3.3 post=    and then more texts and more
   ```
4. put these 3 (pre, acronym, post) in an array.

Any help will be appreciated since I am new to python.

Comment: That's a pretty confusing description.

Comment: @timgeb I did my best to describe it

Comment: @Rebin please be a bit more clear

Comment: It will always be a two step operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but maybe it's enough to help you.

```
import re
import numpy

# open the file? 
test_string = " a lot of text read from file ... Department of Something is called (DoS) and then more texts and more text..."
regex_acronym = r'\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[A-Z]\b\.?'

ra = re.compile(regex_acronym)
for m in ra.finditer(test_string):
    print m.start(), m.group(), m.span()
    n = len(m.group()) * 2
    regex_pre_post = r"((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,%d})(" % n
    regex_pre_post += regex_acronym 
    regex_pre_post += ")((?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,%d})" % n
    found= re.findall(regex_pre_post, test_string)
    print found

    found = found[0] # For a single match, just do this.
    pre = found[0]
    acro = found[1]
    post = found[2]
    print pre, acro, post
```

Will give you:

```
69 DoS (69, 72)
[('file ... Department of Something is called (', 'DoS', ') and then more texts and more')]
file ... Department of Something is called ( DoS ) and then more texts and more
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a very correct answer. Except that I want these 3 components (pre, acronym, post) separate. now the are in a list and when I "print found[0] " it does print every thing. how can I separate these 3?

Comment: thank your. very correct. Another question. is using Regular expression correct for this question?

Comment: Well yes, unless you know the acronyms in advance, regexs are not a bad idea, I suppose :)

Comment: is ther a way to get rid of the ( ) around the DoS ? since some of the acronym may not have left/right paren. So now if I delete the ( ) from  the input file, the code does not return the 6 words for pre and post.